# Reject edit suggestions on old revisions

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, suggested-edits

If somebody submits an edit and the post has changed in the meantime, the edit fails with an error message and the user needs to resubmit it on the latest revision. The same doesn't happen with edit suggestions; [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/46367) was started before [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6023580/revisions), but submitted 8 seconds after. Since the edit suggestion was using the text from revision 2, the diff makes it look like Tim is suggesting a bunch of terrible changes.

Can the system show the same error message 2k users get if a user submits an edit suggestion and the post has already been edited in the interim?

Comment: @Jarrod I think such thing is implemented (or merging of edits) this better be changed to [meta-tag:status-completed] isn't it? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This isn't implemented; it just happened again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/311057)

Comment: `[status-planned-419-days-ago-and-counting]` <--- Lol. More than 1 year.

Comment: @nhahtdh try more than 4 years... and probably in 20 years it will be more than 24 years. I've pinged devs a lot, so far being ignored 100% of the times. They probably don't care for old bugs/requests. lol

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard 10th anniversary of status planned, they definitely do not care one bit.

Comment: @EkadhSingh more likely a *byte*, which is 8 bits. :D (And yes, over time my anger and frustration for the development team was gone, it's not their fault.)

Comment: @EkadhSingh Similar case: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204571/282094 and more recently: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277018/282094