# Proposal: Free downvoting of answers for users that have 200 rep or less?

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

For some users (talk about myself!) reaching 200 rep can mean *jolly* hard work, and often take up to 2 years to happen because not every user is a "SO-addict" and will daily hunt for "fresh" questions to answer to boost up their rep (Face it, thinking a few hours too long about your own answer on the very same day will mean that you'll be beaten to it by 5 others with identical or even better answers; hence, there will be no longer any point in posting yours as well, "re-inventing the wheel.")

This is why I've thought that the "payment" of rep for downvotes is not unfair *per se*, but should simply be free for users that are still struggling to reach the "magic 200" mark.

I will summarize again:

- Users **between 125 rep** (lowest possible for downvoting anyway) and **199 rep** ought to have the chance to downvote useless or (e. g. in "Unix & Linux") totally non-working and badly tested answers without losing ANY rep, because they're still working hard on reaching their "magic mark."
- From 200 rep, rules should remain the same as they are at the moment.

What do you think about it?

Comment: You only lose 1 rep for downvoting an answer. A single upvote on your answer will gain 10. I would say that is a _fair_ ratio.

Comment: That aside, can you explain what actual problem this is supposed to solve?

Comment: _What do you think about it?_ As written, No.  Why do you get to have free downvotes?  It really isn't all that difficult to get to 200.

Comment: @bluefeet For me it is, as I've already written. And usually it's people with thousands of rep that sit on the high horse and talk like this. So don't tell me what's difficult and what is not.

Comment: The rep needed to downvote is 125 note 100

Comment: Ok, I will fix it.

Comment: @syntaxerror Everyone started at the same point with 1 rep.  By posting quality content questions and answers, you can get to 200 rep.  There are other ways to get rep including suggestion quality edits, etc.

Comment: if there was really a problem getting to the magic threshold, then the threshold should be lowered, not a free downvote loophole created. However, I think the fact that it takes the amount of effort that it does to get to the 200 rep point is a feature, not a failure.

Comment: @bluefeet But not everyone has the persistence to hunt for new questions like maybe you have! Usually when I find time to it, there are usually 2 or three good answers so I can forget about posting mine. That happens in roughly 29 out of 30 cases. (Which also describes the big lot of motivation, of course.) And mind you, that can happen BETWEEN only 2 hours!!

Comment: @syntaxerror If you don't have the persistence or time to invest in the site, then again why do you feel that you need to get a free pass with downvotes?  I am well aware of how quickly answers get posted, but if you post quality answers that might expand with details/content on how to solve the question, that is how you gain rep.

Comment: What about suggested edits? Each approved one gives you 2 rep, up to 2000 rep (IIRC). 100 good suggested edits and... no more problem.

Comment: Maybe I miss the issue but isn't the whole point of SO to have a place where you can find answers and ask questions? Why are people obsessed with getting the rep and the badges? Isn't the journey the reward?

Comment: It would most probably require me the persistence of a geek maybe to be that quick. But it's no secret that the great part on here ARE geeks. (I've seen this mentioned many times somewhere else)

Comment: The persistence of a geek? I don't know what that means. If it means you are not willing to put in the time to get the reputation, then I don't have any sympathy.

Comment: @rene Why are people obsessed? Can't you think of the answer yourself? Because you need to have so-and-so much to comment, to downvote, to this and that. And that's why people MUST hunt for reputation, they just have no other choice! Look at me: I'm stuck in SO main site with this stupid 45. And I need 50 to just give a useful (!) comment. But so far I haven't been able to think of a question general enough to fit on SO. On the other sites - perfect. But *not* there. So I'm stuck...and stuck...and...

Comment: @Oded I don't care if I get any sympathy of you. *Really* not.

Comment: @syntaxerror - I gave you a solution. Suggested edits. You don't care to gain reputation that way? Fine. But don't try to change the system because you can't be bothered to do something you _can_.

Comment: "Suggested edits": I don't feel well in always playing the wise guy and mess around in other's answers or questions. Some others may like that, but not me. Sorry 'bout that. Only in cases of emergency.

Comment: @syntaxerror Again, I ask the same question if you aren't willing to invest in the site with suggested edits, etc., then why do you feel you should get a free pass with downvotes?

Comment: That's fine. Then again - improving formatting, grammar and syntax (no pun intended) is what the Stack Exchange model is _all about_.

Comment: @Oded ...and in your case, if I give a (justified!) PS with a little sarcasm to thank the people who "killed" my handful of rep on SO-Meta within a few minutes, __you__ can't be quick enough to edit it out again. I might as well say, *censor* it. *Wheeling and dealing*, as sociologists would call it. So you could say, with the wrong proposal at hand, some people enjoy to push you towards the electric chair. (Visible here.) All against one. Close to bullying, probably, even.

Comment: @syntaxerror you essentially made a feature request, even when you didn't tag it as such. Downvotes on those usually indicate disagreement, as stated in the help center. And it's Meta rep..... doesn't mean a whole lot.

Comment: No that's no "disagreement". That's because the word "downvote" is part of the question title and they want to give me a good dressing down by just taking the word literally. It feels like a biased trial.

Comment: I removed that sarcastic PS because I believe the suggestion deserves listening to and voting on by the community on its merits. That PS would turn it into an emotional vote - **much more so than you have experienced**. Call compassionate censorship if you so wish - but **it was adding nothing** to your argument, so I removed it **without hesitation**.

Comment: EVEN more? I guess that's already way more than enough! Don't make me laugh. (Had I known that before, I'd just have been reluctant of doing this here with my good name, and just created a throwaway account for it.

Comment: @syntaxerror You came with a proposal. As with every proposal that is made here, it might not be a brilliant idea. The community might not like it. That happens. To all of us. If you're willing to accept criticism, and get over the votes, we can have a constructive discussion. If you come here and expect us to carry you on our shoulders, chanting your name, ..... that does not always happen. Keep it constructive.

Comment: So, taking into account that a rep bonus from linking accounts on SE network is 100 rep, and you only need 125 to downvote, are you saying that all that is needed for a troll account is to get 3 upvotes on an answer and then s/he gets **free** downvoting of every answer?, I don't think so

Comment: Eegads man. What is your deal fella? You made a suggestion people clearly don't like and are therefore down voting it. @Bluefeet has even made several attempts to to ask you why you feel you should get the ability to downvote with out putting the work in. Why are you taking this so personally? Chill out have a beer or something.

Comment: status-declined

Comment: A beer? Yes that would really be a good idea, instead of facing all this madness going on at the moment.

Comment: This is actually rather mild for meta. Welcome to the madhouse...

Comment: Uh ... er ... Thanks. :P Although you're in fact wrong (or just trying to comfort me?): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A..-100+is%3Aquestion This is the only one I've found with more than -100. And currently 14 with -50. Seeing how many questions are there in total, this is maybe less than 0.1%.

Comment: ... that is still around @syntaxerror. ;)

Comment: Survivors bias. You are not taking deleted questions into account ;)

Comment: AHHH! Yes OK granted. I could easily delete this one too now (or request it for deletion if I cannot do it myself), however I think I'm no chicken who has to go *down to that level* (no pun intended). :) Sometimes one apparently just got to face the music methinks. ;-)

Comment: I remember the "white people only" stack overflow question.  Ah the downvoting, the glorious glorious downvoting

Comment: P.s. this a legitimate (if unpopular) suggestion, I encorage you to leave it

Comment: @Richard ...granted...on condition that it will be upvoted just a little the next days, though. :) Otherwise it might just disappear one day or another, however that day could also be one day in next year's summer. I would normally do the same as with forum threads that fell out of favor with "tha crowd": i. e. let it die silently and surely *without* a hundred trumpeters signaling / announcing it before ;)

Comment: @syntaxerror started a discussion that produced pages of conversation and insight. He was rewarded with -42. Is there something broken here?

Comment: @jww nothing broken - members disagreed and downvoted as such, the system is working fine.

Answer (score 26):

Changing such a fundamental thing about how the site operates requires an extremely good reason. Something that benefits the site as a whole, to a great degree.

The lack of reputation is not one such reason - you need to earn the reputation and put in the time in the site if you want to participate in it more meaningfully.

The biggest problem with 0 rep loss for downvoting answers is that it opens up too much of a window for abuse - downvoting competing answers, downvoting answer because we don't like the avatar and so on. There needs to be something that stops spurious downvotes on answers - the -1 reputation is the *minimal* possible penalty. Consider that a single upvote on an answer give one 10 reputation - the ratio is more than generous.

---

The solution to the rep issue? Gain reputation. You don't have to ask or answer in order to gain reputation at this level - suggested edits are a great mechanism to improve the site and gain reputation at the same time.

You get 2 rep for every approved suggested edit - good suggested edits improve formatting, grammar and spelling. Which doesn't mean you change the *meaning* of the post, but *are* improving it for *everyone*.

If you are reluctant to use this mechanism and/or are not willing to put in the time to post good questions/answers, then, yes, you are left out. So is life.