# How to deal with a suggested edit on a revision that has already been edited?

Tags: discussion, support, review, edits, suggested-edits

Based on this questions:

[Suggested edits can be submitted even after a concurrent edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204571/suggested-edits-can-be-submitted-even-after-a-concurrent-edit)

[Is concurrent editing detection working? (Answer: yes, but only if everyone is slow enough)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65404/is-concurrent-editing-detection-working-answer-yes-but-only-if-everyone-is-s?rq=1)

Today it happened to me that I was editing a question and at the same time, it was being edited by a user which has privileges to edit directly. Therefore, my edit seem to be as writing back what the user originally posted.

I will write a little example to understand this, let's say he wrote:

`How can I does this?`

Then the edit of the other user is changed to:

`How can I do this?` (he corrected the spelling)

So then, my suggested edit seems to be

`How can I do this?` -> `How can I does this?`

It seems like I am making the post worse even though I just modified a little part of it, that it's not the spelling.

How can I deal with this?

This is the suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11654848

I ONLY changed the indentation and not any word of it, therefore it seems that I tried to make it worse..

Comment: You can submit new edit suggestion, as far as I can tell it will be "merged" into your existing suggestion. Hurry up, 2 already voted to reject. That said, one rejection won't cause any harm, it won't cost you any rep and won't give any ban. (Only several rejections in a row will give an edit ban)

Comment: However it's worth nothing that when you have less than 2k, it is asked that you fix everything wrong with the post that you can see rather than only a few things...